# How can I correctly position multiple texts inside div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to  create a biography page for "about us", and I was able to have an image on the left side and text on the right. However, when I use `<h3>` tag for name, and `<p>` for some writing, the texts get laid side by side, instead of `<h3>` on top, and `<p>` on the bottom. For example:

```
How it looks like now:
[image] [h3text] [ptext]
[image] [h3text] [ptext]

How I want:
[image] [h3text]
         [ptext]
[image] [h3text]
         [ptext]
```

I tried changing `display`, and played around with margin, width, and so on, but I wasn't able to make it... How can I achieve this using CSS?

```css
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#mainContainer {
    width: 1139px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
#bioContainer {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 110px;
    background-color: white;
}

.bio {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;

}
.bio img {
    width: 130px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: block;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="bioContainer">
        <div class="bio">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="woman">
            <h3>name</h3>
            <p>some random text</p>
            <p>some random text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bio">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="woman">
            <h3>name</h3>
            <p>some random text</p>
            <p>some random text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bio">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="woman">
            <h3>name</h3>
            <p>some random text</p>
            <p>some random text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<section>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="bioContainer">
        <div class="bio">
          <div class='bio-image'>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="woman">
          </div>
           <div class='bio-text'>
             <h3>name</h3>
              <p>some random text</p>
              <p>some random text</p>
           </div>
         </div>
         
         <div class="bio">
          <div class='bio-image'>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="woman">
          </div>
           <div class='bio-text'>
             <h3>name</h3>
              <p>some random text</p>
              <p>some random text</p>
           </div>
         </div>
         
        <div class="bio">
          <div class='bio-image'>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="woman">
          </div>
           <div class='bio-text'>
             <h3>name</h3>
              <p>some random text</p>
              <p>some random text</p>
           </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Wrapping image and text in their own divs will do the job. You dont even need to edit css, flex will do job.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bio {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.bio img {
  float: left;
}
h3, p {
  margin-left: 160px;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="bioContainer">
        <div class="bio">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="woman">
            <h3>name</h3>
            <p>some random text</p>
            <p>some random text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bio">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="woman">
            <h3>name</h3>
            <p>some random text</p>
            <p>some random text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bio">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="woman">
            <h3>name</h3>
            <p>some random text</p>
            <p>some random text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </section>
```

No need for any display stuff, just use `float` and `margin` properties.
Sorry if this doesn't answer your question!

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your markup and since you already use `flex` you can set `.bio` flow to `column` and set the image position to `absolute`. Something like that maybe?

```css
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#mainContainer {
    width: 1139px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
#bioContainer {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 110px;
    background-color: white;
}

.bio {
    display: flex;
      flex-flow: column; /* add this */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;

}
.bio img {
    width: 130px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    /*display: block;*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="bioContainer">
        <div class="bio">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="woman">
            <h3>name</h3>
            <p>some random text</p>
            <p>some random text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bio">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="woman">
            <h3>name</h3>
            <p>some random text</p>
            <p>some random text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bio">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="woman">
            <h3>name</h3>
            <p>some random text</p>
            <p>some random text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </section>
```